# Can you fire a callback function when SweetAlert2 advances to next item in queue?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I'm using sweetalert2.
I'm chaining multiple modals using a queue, just like in the [example on their main page](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#chaining-modals).
Is there a way to fire my callback function every time someone hits "Next" to go to the next modal in the queue?

I'm sure I can hack something together using `inputValidator`, but that's abusing a feature intended to do something else. Is there an official way to just run custom code between modals in the queue?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation wasn't clear, but apparently, `preConfirm` runs every time you advance to a different modal.